# Lost decimals in MySQL

Tags: mysql, double, vb.net-2010

I have a MySQL InnoDB table, one of the columns is defined as double and have stored a number 16155.987841701322 but if I perform a query from VB.NET returns
16155.9878417013

From MySQL Workbench I can see all the digits in the DB, but from VB:NET i get two digit less.

Why didn't return all the digits?

I make a little code to perform conversion test

```
Dim OdometerDbl As Double = 16155.987841701322
Dim OdometerStr As String

OdometerStr = CStr(OdometerDbl)
```

After this I get 16155.987841701322 in OdometerDbl and 16155.9878417013 in OdometerStr; so is a VB.NET Double to String conversion issue.

Theres any way to get around this or a better way to convert a Double to String without losing decimals?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html  How is the column defined?  Double(17,12) or higher? my guess is 15,10 which is why the last 2 digits are falling off.   But be warned Double is the same as float in that, "Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to problems"  Maybe you want [FIXED Point Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) instead of [Floating point types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html).

Comment: @xQbert The thing is that the value is already store in the DB. When I receive the value in VB.NET I get to digit less than the number stored in the DB.

Comment: so the result Set returned from your .net query is only returning 10 digits of the decimal instead of 12?  that seems odd to me.  Are you sure it's not a display issue where you're limiting the display to just 10 digits after decimal?  What happens if you multiply the value in the result set by 1000 do you see the missing 2 values?  if so, then you have a problem in the rendering of the value, not the returning of it.

Comment: @E_Blue exactly 10 digit after the `.` ? not a coincidence... something force the printing/round format [edit:] +1 for the print of val*1000

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411931/vb-net-displaying-certain-portions-of-a-decimal-value  Turn on `option strict` so no implicit conversions take place. Which may be causing the truncation.

Comment: It looks (to me) like 16155.9878417013 is at the limit of a `double`'s precision, the other two digits are a conversion error and can't/shouldn't be used.

Comment: @xQbert I'm placing the data directly in to a string, so no digit limits. I'm doing Odometer = reader("odometer")

Comment: @Vatev The closest double to 16155.987841701322 is 16155.987841701322395238094031810760498046875. The closest to 16155.9878417013 is 16155.987841701300567365251481533050537109375. They are different, so it is not a matter of the limits of double precision.

Comment: @xQbert I do it without success, The decimals are being lost in the Double to String VB.NET conversion. I add more info in the original question.

Comment: Maybe... wholenumber.ToString("####.############")

Comment: @xQbert Nope, same result. :(

Answer (score 0):

From the example above

```
OdometerStr = OdometerDbl.ToString("R")
```

or

```
OdometerStr = OdometerDbl.ToString("G17")
```

**References:**

[Why Is ToString() Rounding My Double Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105096/why-is-tostring-rounding-my-double-value)

[VB.NET Converting Double Value to String = Precision loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016718/vb-net-converting-double-value-to-string-precision-loss)